# Magento create a custom module

Tags: magento-enterprise

I would like to create a custom module. I have taken the following setps my code are below.

app\code\local\Amzad\OrderComment\etc\config.xml

```
<models>
  <ordercomment>
    <class>Amzad_OrderComment_Model</class>
  </ordercomment>
    <ordercomment_resource>
        <class>Amzad_OrderComment_Model_Resource</class>
        <entities>
            <config>
                <table>ordercomment_config</table>
            </config>
        </entities>
    </ordercomment_resource>
</models>
```

app\code\local\Amzad\OrderComment\Model\Resource\Config\Collection.php

```
   class Amzad_OrderComment_Model_Resource_Config_Collection extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract {
        protected function _construct()
        {
            $this->_init('ordercomment/config');
        }
    }
```

app\code\local\Amzad\OrderComment\Model\Resource\Config.php

```
    class Amzad_OrderComment_Model_Resource_Config extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract
    {
        protected function _construct()
        {
            $this->_init('ordercomment/config', 'id');
        }
    }
```

app\code\local\Amzad\OrderComment\Model\Config.php

```
    class Amzad_OrderComment_Model_Config extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
    {

        protected function _construct()
        {
            $this->_init('ordercomment/config');
        }
    }
```

Following 2 lines does not give me any output.

```
  $collection = Mage::getModel('ordercomment/config')->getCollection();
  echo "\n" . (string)$collection->getSelect()->limit(1);
```

php_error.log

```
 PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getSelect() on a non-object in
```

Could someone help me resolve this issue.

Comment: Can you share your source code via git?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're missing a `<resourceModel>ordercomment_resource</resourceModel>` node in `config/global/models/ordercomment` node.

/Edit: Something like:

```
<config>
...
  <global>
    ...
    <models>
      <ordercomment>
        <class>Amzad_OrderComment_Model</class>
        <resourceModel>ordercomment_resource</resourceModel>
      </ordercomment>
      <ordercomment_resource>
        <class>Amzad_OrderComment_Model_Resource</class>
        <entities>
            <config>
                <table>ordercomment_config</table>
            </config>
        </entities>
      </ordercomment_resource>
...
    </models>
...
  </global>
...
</config>
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion ... I have added 
          <resourceModel>tprg_ordercomment_resource</resourceModel>  and 
          <resourceModel>ordercomment_resource</resourceModel>  remain unlucky

Comment: There's only one resource model per model, so you can't add both. Did you clear the cache?

Comment: <resourceModel>ordercomment_resource</resourceModel> worked but there was few error found in php_error.log

Comment: You can open a new question for the other errors, since this one is fixed.

Comment: Resolve the error.. Posted an answer below with working code. Thanks a lot. you  are a star !!

Answer (score 1):

Is this your complete config?

Change it to:

```
<config>
    <global>
        <models>
          <ordercomment>
            <class>Tprg_OrderComment_Model</class>
          </ordercomment>
            <ordercomment_resource>
                <class>Tprg_OrderComment_Model_Resource</class>
                <entities>
                    <config>
                        <table>ordercomment_config</table>
                    </config>
                </entities>
            </ordercomment_resource>
        </models>    
    </global>
</config>
```

And I assume you have the module xml file in `app/etc/modules`.

Comment: It is a working module. Just adding a custom module.

Comment: And it is under global section.

Comment: you are talking about custom model, not module, correct me if I'm wrong. Beside this your code looks good. Did you clean the cache?

Comment: custom model in a working module !! :)

Comment: @m82amjad make the comment about the model, don't edit posts for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Its working now !! Thanks you everybody !!!

app\code\local\Amzad\OrderComment\etc\config.xml

```
<models>
  <ordercomment>
      <class>Amzad_OrderComment_Model</class>
      <resourceModel>ordercomment_resource</resourceModel>
  </ordercomment>
    <ordercomment_resource>
        <class>Amzad_OrderComment_Model_Resource</class>
        <entities>
            <config>
                <table>ordercomment_config</table>
            </config>
        </entities>
    </ordercomment_resource>
</models>
```

app\code\local\Amzad\OrderComment\Model\Config.php

```
    class Amzad_OrderComment_Model_Config extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
    {

        protected function _construct()
        {
            $this->_init('ordercomment/config');
        }
    }
```

app\code\local\Amzad\OrderComment\Model\Resource\Config.php

```
    class Amzad_OrderComment_Model_Resource_Config extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract
    {
        protected function _construct()
        {
            $this->_init('ordercomment/config', 'id');
        }
    }
```

app\code\local\Amzad\OrderComment\Model\Resource\Config\Collection.php

```
 class Amzad_OrderComment_Model_Resource_Config_Collection extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract {
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('ordercomment/config');
    }
}


    $collection = Mage::getModel('ordercomment/config')->getCollection();
    echo "\n" . (string)$collection->getSelect()->limit(1);
```

Here is some sample if you would like to retrieve and save data .

```
     Mage::getModel('ordercomment/config')->getCollection()
    ->getFirstItem()->getLastExportId();
    Mage::getModel('ordercomment/config')->load(1)->getLastExportId();
    $model = Mage::getModel('ordercomment/config')->load(1)->addData(array('last_export_id'=>$maxId));
    $model->setId(1)->save();
```